# Not able to get old user instance before edits, and compare fields to get field edited

Tags: python, django

I have a model for logging changes and is attempting to get the fields edited upon user edit to log it. I'm currently trying to loop through the old user object and the user object after edits to compare the field(s) through `object._meta.get_fields()`, and the plan is to log/get the field(s) that are different.

One of the problems I have is that when I print the user object under ("#breakpoint 1"), I get the before-edited user object, but when I use it as a parameter in the method ("# breakpoint 2") it prints the edited user object, instead of the before-edited object.

How can I fix this? Alternatively, is there a better way to log the fields edited?

## View

```
def editUser(request, pk):

    # Query appropriate user based on pk returned in url
    user = User.objects.get(pk = pk)

    # Get the EditUserForm and add the user as instance
    edit_user_form = EditUserForm(instance = user)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        # Bind data to the form class, and add the user as instance
        edit_user_form = EditUserForm(request.POST, error_class=DivErrorList, instance = user)

        old_user_instance = user
        # breakpoint 1
        print(old_user_instance)


        # Validate form inputs
        if edit_user_form.is_valid():

            # Save edits
            edit_user_form.save()

            # Log change
            ChangeLog.log_user_change(old_user_instance, request.user.id)

            # Give the user successful feedback and redirect
            messages.success(request, successMessage('Redigering', 'bruker'))
            return redirect('user', pk)

        else:
            # If form inputs is invalid, give user feedback
            messages.error(request, 'Error')

    context = {
        'user': user,
        'edit_user_form': edit_user_form,
    }

    # Render request, template and context
    return render(request, 'users/backend/user/user_edit.html', context)
```

## log_user_change method

The method is attached to the ChangeLog model, and is planned to use the log_update constructor defined in a manager to log to DB.

```
def log_user_change(old_user_instance, request):

        user = User.objects.get(pk = old_user_instance.id)

        # breakpoint 2
        print(old_user_instance)

        user_fields = user._meta.get_fields()
        old_user_fields = old_user_instance._meta.get_fields()

        ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(user)

        for old_user_fields in user_fields:
            if not old_user_fields in user_fields:
                """
                ChangeLog.objects.log_updae(
                    user = request,
                    content_type = ct.pk,
                    object_id = user.pk,
                    changes = user_fields,
                )
                """
                print('changes: ' + old_user_fields)
            else:
                print('no changes')
```

Any input is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because when you do `old_user_instance = user`, you make `old_user_instance` point to `user`, instead of making a copy of it. Then when you save your form, both gets modified. Perhaps try `old_user_instance = User()` with the same parameters as `user` and see if it changes something.

Comment: Of course, this solved the problem. Changed now. Thank you! Do you have any idea why the conditional in the method is failing? Are you not able to compare fields this way?

Comment: Well I think when you do `if not old_user_fields in user_fields`, you are checking if the field of the old instance is in the new instance, when instead you should check if the value of the field of the old instance is the same as the value of the same field on the new instance, IMO.